# for loop in a matrix using index

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I wrote this code:

```
N=20
matrix = numpy.zeros([3*N,N])
for j1 in range (N):
    for i1 in range (0*N, 1*N):
        matrix[i1,j1] = numpy.array(readFile['alpha'])[0,0,i1-0*N,j1])
    for i2 in range(1*N, 2*N):
        matrix[i2,j2] = numpy.array(readFile['alpha'])[0,0,i2-1*N,j1])
    for i3 in range (2*N, 3*N):
        matrix[i3,j3] = numpy.array(readFile['alpha'])[0,0,i3-2*N,j1])
print(matrix)
```

NB: readFile is just reading file using h5py library. I had No problem with that!

My question is how to simplify this code (I only wrote i1, i2, i3, but in my case I have i1, ..., i200), what I am looking for is instead of writing all this lines concerning i, I want to define an index as index = 0, so the code will become:

```
matrix = numpy.zeros([3*N,N])
index = 0
for j1 in range (N):
    for i_(index+1) in range (index*N, (index+1)*N):
        matrix[i_(index+1),j1] = numpy.array(readFile['alpha'])[0,0,i_[index+1]-index*N,j1])
```

Those lines allow to fill the matrix[i1,j1] with index = 0. When the index = 1, I will obtain matrix[i2,j1] and when the index = 2 I will obtain matrix[i3,j1]. Therefore, I guess that I need a loop index = index + 1
Do you have any idea on how I can create this loop on index?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Where do j2, j3....come from?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where you get `j2` and `j3` from, but assuming they were all `j1` as indicated by your second code block:

Add an intermediate loop to `range(200)` and use that loop's variable to dynamically calculate your `i` ranges.

```
N = 20
matrix = numpy.zeros([3 * N, N])
for j1 in range(N):
    for i in range(200):
        for i1 in range(i * N, (i + 1) * N):
            matrix[i1, j1] = numpy.array(readFile['alpha'])[0, 0, i1 - i * N, j1]
```

Now your 200 can become 2000 by just changing the second loop's `range`.